# Could not read Spark streaming data

Tags: python, spark-streaming

I am trying to read streaming data, using Spark Python, and change the data format for the streaming data. But it seems that I even cannot read the stream...

Here are my steps:

1. I opened one terminal, cd to the input data folder, then type command line

   ```
   ls part-* | xargs -I % sh -c '{ cat %; sleep 5;}' | nc -lk 9999
   ```
2. Then I open another terminal, type `setenv SPARK_HOME /user/abc/Downloads/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/`, so that I could run Spark locally. Then I type command `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --master local /user/abc/test.py localhost 9999` to run my code.

Below is the code, I am simply testing whether I am reading the streaming data and then change the data format... But it always shows error: `16/01/28 22:41:37 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver
16/01/28 22:41:37 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStart
16/01/28 22:41:37 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Receiver started again
16/01/28 22:41:37 INFO SocketReceiver: Connecting to localhost:9999
16/01/28 22:41:37 INFO SocketReceiver: Connected to localhost:9999
16/01/28 22:41:37 INFO SocketReceiver: Closed socket to localhost:9999
16/01/28 22:41:37 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Socket data stream had no more data`

If I re-run `ls part-* | xargs -I % sh -c '{ cat %; sleep 5;}' | nc -lk 9999`, it still shows the same error.... Do you know how to solve the problem?

```
import sys
import re

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext


sc = SparkContext(appName="test")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


def get_tuple(r):
    m = re.search('\[(.*?)\]',r)
    s = m.group(1)
    fs = s.split(',')
    for i in range(len(fs)):
        if i > 1:
            fs[i] = float(fs[i])
    return fs


def main():
    indata = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    inrdd = indata.map(lambda r: get_tuple(r))
    Features = Row('feature_vec')
    features_rdd = inrdd.map(lambda r: Features(r))
    features_rdd.pprint(num=10)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Just for testing purposes could you launch nc server  like this and see if it works: while true; do echo testmessage; done | nc -lk 9999

Comment: Thank you so much @facha , this is a good way to test! I have learned more from you! Just solved the problem, the spark command should add `[*]`, like this: `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --master local[*] /user/abc/test.py localhost 9999`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The Spark command line should add [*] for Spark streaming, like this:

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --master local[*] /user/abc/test.py localhost 9999
```

Then the output will appear